# Turn off "smart semicolon" in Visual Studio C# editor

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2019, it likes to try to guess where it should put the semicolon when you hit it.  Often it will jump to a completely different line or insert newlines.  Every time it does anything besides append it as the next character, this is extremely disruptive, and I have to go back and fix what it broke.  This is akin to the disruptive "Automatic brace completion" which always puts braces where I don't want them, but can be turned off.  I can't find anywhere to turn off the semicolon behavior.  Is there any way to turn this feature off?

Most of the time when the semicolon misbehaves, it's because I hit it by mistake, but rather than hitting backspace, I now have a bigger mess to clean up.  And I've never had a situation where it did something extra that I wanted it to do.

Some examples, with * being the cursor location:

```
// between a ) and ; 
Foo()*;
// inserts an extra space
Foo();* ;

// before an existing semicolon:
return null*;
// moves the old semicolon to the next line:
return null;*
;

// pressing semicolon in the middle of a multi-line function call:
string path = Path.Combine(
    "C:\\",
    "b"*
    "filename.txt");
// moves the cursor to the end of the block and inserts a "; " before ";":
string path = Path.Combine(
    "C:\\",
    "b"
    "filename.txt");* ;
```

Comment: I have never experienced behavior like this in VS2019. Can you provide some concrete examples of what code you're terminating and how it's getting formatted? Based on your description it sounds like you have semicolons that end up on their own line sometimes, and I'd love to see how that actually looks.

Comment: I added some examples to explain what it does.

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed that assist with formatting like Productivity Power Tools, or ReSharper? I cannot recreate this behavior no matter how I change my code style settings in base VS2019.

Comment: Maybe it's an unfortunate interaction with VsVim?  That's the only extension that would affect text editing.  Although for completeness, I'll list Roslynator 2019, Visual Studio Spell Checker, Visual Studio IntelliCode, and Visual Studio Rich Navigation [Preview]

Comment: VsVim and Rostlynator are both strong candidates. I get the logic behind the particular behavior shown here, and can see how it could be a desired behavior for some. It's similar to how VS Code will automatically slap a close HTML tag in even though I'm trying to wrap an existing tag. Best to try turning off each one until it stops doing it and then dig into the settings of the offending extension. I doubt it's permanently enabled.

Comment: I disabled every single extension, even the ones that should have nothing to do with text editing.  It still behaves the same.  I am running version 16.9.0, if that helps (like if there has been an update that fixes this behavior recently).

Comment: Well I'm at a loss. For me your first two examples result in the ; being overwritten. The third one just results in an error. I am on a slightly newer version of 2019, but I don't think this is some sort of glitch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio 16.10 adds a new configuration option to control this:

Text Editor -> C# -> Intellisense -> Automatically complete statements on semicolon

With that checked, I get the problematic behavior described in the question.  When I uncheck that option, it works as it did before.

Comment: You, sir, are my hero. This was driving me absolutely bonkers (in Visual Studio 2022, I never experienced it in 2019).

Comment: Unchecking this option didn't do anything and it still autocompletes as soon as I hit the semicolon key; does anyone know why this is and how to fix it?